# Is it possible to send large JSON data to IoT Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm asking this question behalf of a hardware developer (i don't have much knowledge in device side).

Right now IoT hub receiving data from the device every 2 minutes, due to some reasons planning to store the data locally with the device and send that in every 30 minutes. But the problem is, data is not getting saved to storage. 2 minute's data is getting saved to storage. But the 30 minute's data is not 
getting properly saved to storage. Only the first object in the array is getting saved.

I'm using Stream analytics to process the data from IoT hub and storing the data to table storage.

Current message Json data (every 2 minute) is :

```
{
    "deviceid": "testdevice12",
    "BatteryVoltage": "31.31",
    "PanelVoltage": "0.00",
    "PanelCurrent": "0.00",
    "OutputVoltage": "31.29",
    "OutputCurrent": "4.94",
    "RSSI": "13",
    "FreeHeapSize": "86.884",
    "timestamp": 1540470493
}
```

For 30 minutes it will be like the following:

```
[{
    "deviceid": "testdevice12",
    "BatteryVoltage": "31.31",
    "PanelVoltage": "0.00",
    "PanelCurrent": "0.00",
    "OutputVoltage": "31.29",
    "OutputCurrent": "4.94",
    "RSSI": "13",
    "FreeHeapSize": "86.884",
    "timestamp": 1540470493
}, {
    "deviceid": "testdevice12",
    "BatteryVoltage": "31.29",
    "PanelVoltage": "0.00",
    "PanelCurrent": "0.00",
    "OutputVoltage": "31.28",
    "OutputCurrent": "4.93",
    "RSSI": "0",
    "FreeHeapSize": "86.884",
    "timestamp": 1540470558
}, {
    "deviceid": "testdevice12",
    "BatteryVoltage": "31.30",
    "PanelVoltage": "0.00",
    "PanelCurrent": "0.00",
    "OutputVoltage": "31.29",
    "OutputCurrent": "4.94",
    "RSSI": "5",
    "FreeHeapSize": "86.884",
    "timestamp": 1540470621
}, {
    "deviceid": "testdevice12",
    "BatteryVoltage": "31.31",
    "PanelVoltage": "0.00",
    "PanelCurrent": "0.00",
    "OutputVoltage": "31.30",
    "OutputCurrent": "4.94",
    "RSSI": "5",
    "FreeHeapSize": "86.884",
    "timestamp": 1540470684
}, {
    "deviceid": "testdevice12",
    "BatteryVoltage": "31.30",
    "PanelVoltage": "0.00",
    "PanelCurrent": "0.00",
    "OutputVoltage": "31.28",
    "OutputCurrent": "4.94",
    "RSSI": "7",
    "FreeHeapSize": "86.884",
    "timestamp": 1540470760
}]
```

Here is the ASA query i'm Using:

```
WITH [StreamData] AS ( SELECT * FROM [IoTHubStream] WHERE [ObjectType] IS NULL -- Filter out device info and command responses ) 
SELECT IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId AS DeviceId, PanelVoltage, PanelCurrent, BatteryVoltage, BatteryCurrent, OutputVoltage, OutputCurrent, Temperature, Humidity, EventProcessedUtcTime, PartitionId, EventEnqueuedUtcTime, * INTO [DeviceDataHistory] FROM [StreamData]
```

Comment: I think the title is misleading as it seems the problem lies in the ASA query. Can you post that one? I think the query does not handle the array well.

Comment: I don't think it is ASA query issue, because i tested the same data with my ASA i got the result.

Comment: Added my ASA query to the post, please have a look.

Comment: Hmm thats weird. I thing we can test it in another way too. Please use IoT Hub device simulator together with Visual Studio Code:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.azure-iot-toolkit
There is information how to send json data to the IoT Hub - try to send your json and check result. If problem does not appear I think its about data serialization on real device. Please let me know the result.

Comment: OK, let me try, need to install VS code

Comment: Tried as you said, only the last object in the array got inserted to the table storage.Also no error shown.

Comment: Ok so now maybe try to send simple array and see if data is inserted to the table storage. I suppose its the problem between ASA and table Storage.

Comment: I already tried that, it works fine. Array with single object get inserted successfully. Then tried with two objects, only the first object got inserted.

Comment: I will try to somehow reproduce this case. If I have any details I will get back and share it.

Comment: Could you please tell what are PartitionKey and RowKey values for the table? How they are assigned from the data sent from ASA?

Comment: It is DeviceId and eventenqueuedutctime. You mean duplicate rows, Oh that is a main factor, i just forgotten. So i need to change the RowKey to a unique one right?

Comment: @Alex, please check my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it -finally.
There are few points:
1. JSON payload with cached data structure should have struture like below:

```
{
 "topic": "cachedData",
  "deviceId": "testdevice12",
  "data":
[{
"BatteryVoltage": "31.31",
"PanelVoltage": "0.00",
"PanelCurrent": "0.00",
"OutputVoltage": "31.29",
"OutputCurrent": "4.94",
"RSSI": "13",
"FreeHeapSize": "86.884",
"timestamp": 1540470493
}, {
"BatteryVoltage": "31.29",
"PanelVoltage": "0.00",
"PanelCurrent": "0.00",
"OutputVoltage": "31.28",
"OutputCurrent": "4.93",
"RSSI": "0",
"FreeHeapSize": "86.884",
"timestamp": 1540470558
}, {
"BatteryVoltage": "31.30",
"PanelVoltage": "0.00",
"PanelCurrent": "0.00",
"OutputVoltage": "31.29",
"OutputCurrent": "4.94",
"RSSI": "5",
"FreeHeapSize": "86.884",
"timestamp": 1540470621
}, {
"BatteryVoltage": "31.31",
"PanelVoltage": "0.00",
"PanelCurrent": "0.00",
"OutputVoltage": "31.30",
"OutputCurrent": "4.94",
"RSSI": "5",
"FreeHeapSize": "86.884",
"timestamp": 1540470684
}, {
"BatteryVoltage": "31.30",
"PanelVoltage": "0.00",
"PanelCurrent": "0.00",
"OutputVoltage": "31.28",
"OutputCurrent": "4.94",
"RSSI": "7",
"FreeHeapSize": "86.884",
"timestamp": 1540470760
}]
}
```

2. Azure Stream Analytics should look like below:

   ```
    SELECT   
     iothubAlias.deviceId,
     arrayElement.ArrayValue.BatteryVoltage,
     arrayElement.ArrayValue.PanelVoltage,
     arrayElement.ArrayValue.PanelCurrent,
     arrayElement.ArrayValue.OutputVoltage,
     arrayElement.ArrayValue.OutputCurrent,
     arrayElement.ArrayValue.RSSI,
     arrayElement.ArrayValue.FreeHeapSize,
     arrayElement.ArrayValue.timestamp
   INTO [DeviceDataHistory]
   FROM [IoTHubStream] as iothubAlias  
   CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(iothubAlias.data) AS arrayElement
   ```

To retrieve multiple rows from the input you have to use "GetArrayElements" - you can read more here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-parsing-json

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/stream-analytics/reference/getarrayelements-azure-stream-analytics

3. Remember to set PartitionKey and RowKey for the Azure Table set as output for the Azure Stream Analytics:

[image]

And final result look like below:

[image]

Try and let me know if it helped.

Comment: my data size is less than 256kb. My confusion is the JSON format i'm using for bulk data is correct or not?

Comment: OK so now I got it - description is confusing because you are saying about storage but not no for device but you mean table storage :) so I thought you are storing it locally and it is not passed to IoT Hub.
I think that bulk data is correct - the problem is I suppose between ASA and Table Storage. How do you push data from ASA to Table Storage? How query looks like? Are you using "SELECT *" in your query?

Comment: Sorry for the confusions, Here is my query:

`WITH 
    [StreamData]
AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM [IoTHubStream]
    WHERE
        [ObjectType] IS NULL -- Filter out device info and command responses
)


SELECT
    IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId AS DeviceId,
    PanelVoltage,
    PanelCurrent,
    BatteryVoltage,
    BatteryCurrent,
    OutputVoltage,
    OutputCurrent,
    Temperature,
    Humidity,
    EventProcessedUtcTime,
    PartitionId,
    EventEnqueuedUtcTime,
    * 
INTO
    [DeviceDataHistory]
FROM
    [StreamData]`

Comment: I just edited the post, you can see the query there.

Comment: Great let me verify.

Comment: Thank you so much, let me try this and will let you know, now in the middle of other tasks, will try after that. Thanks again.

Comment: That worked fine, mistake was the duplicate RowKey. Thank you.